# How to bring up System settings GUI tool using Cygwin-X over SSH

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh

I am connecting to my headless ubuntu 12.04 server using SSH and I want to make some changes to system settings.

There is no desktop manager running so VNC is not an option for me.

I have Cygwin-X installed on my windows laptop. Is there any way to bring up the System Settings GUI tool using Cygwin-X over SSH?

Comment: What are the settings you want to change?

Comment: I am trying to make changes to Network settings. I'm sure there is a way to do it on the command line but I want to know how it can be done using X forwarding over SSH. Specifically, I want to know the command to launch the 'System settings' GUI .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, if nothing is messed up you should be able to simple do the following:

```bsh
ssh -Y user@machineIP
```

The `-Y` enables trusted X11 forwarding.

Then to open the system settings program simply type:

```bsh
gnome-control-center
```

Comment: I am aware of this functionality. I am using PuTTY with X11 forwarding enabled and I have Cygwin-X running on my Windows client machine. I just want to know the specific command to launch the 'System Settings' GUI tool.